Missing "Rendered" Viewport Shading option?
The Rendered Viewport Shading options is missing. There are only three options to choose from. I am doing a Blender tutorial and want to see the render, but the icon to do that is not there. Can anyone help? I have tried pressing Z, but it still didn't show.


Hello and welcome. Can you provide a screenshot of Edit > Preferences > System and also the Render Properties. Is it set to Eevee or Cycles?

Under Preferences > Add-ons, search for 'cycles' and make sure that the 'Cycles Render Engine' entry is checked.

Thankes John that fixed it.
